# Double Smithchart with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a smithchart, which has negative impedances, too.
This is how far i got till now:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.smithchart}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[
        yticklabel around circle,
        show origin,
        xtick={-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.5,2,3,4,5,10,20,-20,-10,-5,-4,-3},
    ]

   \addplot[mark=none,line width=2]
       coordinates{
           (1, 0) (1, 0.1) (1,0.2) (1,0.3) (1,0.4) (1,0.5) (1,0.5)
       };
   \end{smithchart}
   \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

The result is not very pleasant, the circles of the y-axis just stop, when the x-values start to get negative:

[image]

The goal would be a look similar to this, but I would be happy, if the y-axis would be continued :)

[image]

EDIT: So I made same progess. first, I could move the outer circle labeling the x-axis:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.smithchart}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[
        yticklabel around circle,
        show origin,
        xtick={-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.5,2,3,4,5,10,20,-20,-10,-5,-4,-3},
        xmin=-0.3, %works quite well
        xmax=-3,    %xmax seems to be always infinty?!?!?
        ticklabel style={opacity=0.5},
    ]

   \addplot[mark=none,line width=2]
       coordinates{
           (1, 0) (1, 0.1) (1,0.2) (1,0.3) (1,0.4) (1,0.5) (1,0.5)
       };
   \end{smithchart}
   \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this, which is not quite satisfying, as xmax is ignored (always near infinty) and drwing lines is just possible inside the old, small (positive-x) circle: [image: x-axis of smithchart moved]

And the next thing, drawing y-circles when x is negative, seems also to be possible in some way.

```
...... %just as before
    \begin{smithchart}[
        yticklabel around circle,
        show origin,
        xtick={-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.5,2,3,4,5,10,20,-20,-10,-5,-4,-3},
        ygrid each nth passes x={-3},
        ticklabel style={opacity=0.5},
    ]

   \addplot[mark=none,line width=2]
       coordinates{
           (1, 0) (1, 0.1) (1,0.2) (1,0.3) (1,0.4) (1,0.5) (1,0.5)
       };
   \end{smithchart}
    .....
```

And the result: [image]

EDIT again: By overlaying two smith charts, it comes again a bit closer to the desired look...
But one can't draw lines, where x is negative!

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.smithchart}    
\makeatletter    
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[
        show origin,
        xtick={-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.5,2,3,4,5,10,20,-20,-10,-5,-4,-3},
        ygrid stop at x={0.2:-.3,-0.2:-.3,  0.5:-.3,-0.5:-.3,  1:-.3,-1:-.3,  2:-3,-2:-2.99,  5:-6,-5:-5.99,},
        xmin=-0.3, %works quite well
        %xmax=-3,   %xmax seems to be alwys infinty?!?!?
        ticklabel style={white,opacity=0},
    ]
   \end{smithchart}

   \begin{smithchart}[
        show origin,
        xtick={-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.5,2,3,4,5,10,20,-20,-10,-5,-4,-3},
        ygrid stop at x={0.2:-3,-0.2:-3,0.5:-3,-0.5:-3,1:-3,-1:-3,  2:-3.01,-2:-3.0,  5:-6.01,-5:-6.0,},
        xmin=-0.3, %works quite well
        %xmax=-3,   %xmax seems to be alwys infinty?!?!?
        ticklabel style={opacity=0},
    ]

   \addplot[mark=none,line width=2]
       coordinates{
           (1, 0) (1, 0.1) (1,0.2) (1,0.3) (1,0.4) (1,0.5) (1,0.5)
       };
   \addplot[mark=none,line width=0.5]
       coordinates{
           (1, 0) (-0.3, 0)  % this one is not drawn outside!!!
       };
   \end{smithchart}
   \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have a solution, but it's not nice. Perhaps I will look deeper in the code in some months, when I have more time.....

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.smithchart}

  \pgfplotsset{
    axis line style={opacity=1},
    every axis label/.append style ={white,opacity=0},
    every tick label/.append style={white,opacity=0}  
  }
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{smithchart}[
        yticklabel around circle,
        show origin,
    clip=false,
        xtick={-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.5,2,3,4,5,10,20,-20,-10,-5,-4},
        ygrid stop at x={0.2:-.3,-0.2:-.3,  0.5:-.365,-0.5:-.365,  1:-.63,-1:-.63,  2:-3,-2:-2.99,  5:-6,-5:-5.99,},
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none,line width=0.4,]
          coordinates{
            (-3.5, 0) (-0.285, 0)
        };  
    \draw[black!30] (1,0) arc (-180:-61:0.5) ;
    \draw[black!30] (1,0) arc (180:61:0.5) ;

    \draw[black!30] (1,0) arc (-180:-116:1) ;
    \draw[black!30] (1,0) arc (180:116:1) ;

    \draw[black!30] (1,0) arc (0:-145:1.43) ;
    \draw[black!30] (1,0) arc (0:145:1.43) ;

    \draw[black!30] (1,0) arc (0:-64:2) ;
    \draw[black!30] (1,0) arc (0:64:2) ;

    \draw[black!30] (1,0) -- (1,1.5) ;
    \draw[black!30] (1,0) -- (1,-1.5) ;


    \draw[mark=none,line width=0.5,]
        circle[radius=1.8]{};
   \end{smithchart}

      \begin{smithchart}[
    clip=false,
        yticklabel around circle,
        show origin,
        xtick={-0.2,-0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,1,1.5,2,3,4,5,10,20,-20,-10,-5,-4},
        ygrid stop at x={0.2:-3.5,-0.2:-3.5,0.5:-3.45,-0.5:-3.45,  1:-3.15,-1:-3.15,  2:-3.01,-2:-3.0,  5:-6.01,-5:-6.0,},
        ticklabel style={opacity=0},
    ]

   \addplot[mark=none,line width=2]
       coordinates{
           (1, 0) (1, 0.1) (1,0.2) (1,0.3) (1,0.4) (1,0.5) (1,0.5)
       };
   \end{smithchart}

   \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

The result is not that nice like the picture I proposed in the beginning, but at least it's not wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

What you want is more a feature request to that library (which cannot do that kind of graphics).

I can assist with one simple item, though: add `clip=false` to suppress clipping of `\addplot` operations -- this will draw your custom axis.

The circles (y grid) which is drawn incompletely is due to the fact that `pgfplots` computes arcs with precise end points - and that appears to be limited to the positive values. The code which does it contains a comment of sorts "this here is the correct, complete circle" and the code to generate that circle. See `\pgfplots@smithchart@draw@yarc` in `tikzlibrarypgfplots.smithchart.code.tex`. If you patch that macro (include the uncommented `\pgfpathellipse` instead of what follows after it), you can get full circles for y grid lines. You will need to handle the clip path somehow, though.

Comment: `clip=false` is a first step :) now I can also draw lines outside. Solving the problem in `\pgfplots@smithchart@draw@yarc` would be the best solution, but overlaying two axises also works quite well as provisional solution (last picture). Do you also have an idea how to draw the "x-axis-circle" bigger, e.g. "from xmin=-0,3 to xmax=-3", so that it doesn't intersect with x=infty? ;)

Comment: I made a couple of experiments for xmax=-3 without success. I would need to dig deeper into that feature request.

Comment: in the semester break (august, september), I will look in the code and look for a way for flexible scaling the outer circle, so that there is no limit to make it smaller or bigger than in the current version. But for now, I dont't have the time for it... :(